# Lagrangian: difference between 2 different Definitions for first kind

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, constrained-dynamics

Let me introduce an exemplary system first for which the Lagrangian and equation of motions are already a given, a particle moving freely inside the surface of a cone pointing downwards and parametrised by $\textbf{r} = \left(\begin{array}{c}\rho\,\cos\varphi\\ \rho\,\sin\varphi\,\\-\dfrac{\rho}{\sqrt{b}}\end{array}\right)$ in order to fulfil the constraint $g:  \rho^2 - b\,z^2 = 0$.

This results to the following Lagrangian: $$L = \dfrac{1}{2}\,m\,\left(\dot{\rho}^2+\rho^2\,\dot{\varphi}^2+\dfrac{\dot{\rho}^2}{b}\right)+m\,g\,\dfrac{\rho}{\sqrt{b}}$$

where the equations of motion are derived:

$q_1 = \rho: \qquad m\,\ddot{\rho}+m\,\dfrac{\ddot{\rho}}{b}-m\,\rho\,\dot{\varphi}-m\,g\,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{b}} = 0$

$q_2 = \varphi: \qquad m\,\rho^2\ddot{\varphi} = 0$

Now there seem to float around 2 different definitions for the Lagrangian of first kind:

$\textbf{1.} \quad \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\partial_{\textstyle \dot{q}_k}L-\partial_{\textstyle q_k}L = \sum_{i} \lambda_i\partial_{\textstyle q_k} g_i \quad \textsf{with $g_i$ being the constraints}$

$\textbf{2.} \quad m\,\mathbf{\ddot{r}} = F + \sum_i\lambda_i\,\nabla g_i$

My only explanation for how those 2 definition equal to one another is by saying:

$m \mathbf{\ddot{r}} = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}}\partial_{\textstyle \dot{q}_k}L$ as well as $F = \partial_{\textstyle q_k}L$.

So do the equation of motions already represent the Lagrangian of first kind, except you got to include the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda_i$? In this example:

$q_1 = \rho: \qquad m\,\ddot{\rho}+m\,\dfrac{\ddot{\rho}}{b}-m\,\rho\,\dot{\varphi}-m\,g\,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{b}} = \lambda_1\,2\,\rho$

$q_2 = \varphi: \qquad m\,\rho^2\ddot{\varphi} = \lambda_2\cdot 0$

not forgetting $\rho = \sqrt{b}\,z$

$q_3 = z: \qquad m \,{b}\,\ddot{z}+m\, \ddot{z} -m\,b\,z\,\dot{\varphi}^2-m\,g = -\lambda_3\,2\,b\,z$

But what are the constraining forces in this scenario? Only the Lagrange multiplier or the whole right side? Provided these are indeed the Lagrange equation of first kind, what I'm not believing myself.

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: I you are referring to the definitions of Lagrange equations - this is my source:  https://www.reibungsphysik.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg204/Lehre/2017_18_WiSe/Energiemethoden/Uebung_und_Tutorien/em-w4.formeln.pdf. $\textbf{The task itself}$ was part of a mock exam, I haven't found it online yet.